# Displaying parent/child data on VFP

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT:

I have tried something like this:

```
public with sharing class dataTableCon { 
public List<Item__c> getItemRecords() {

        // this query needs a where clause, don't leave it unbounded
        List<Item__c> ItemDetailRecords = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                                , Code__c
                                                , Order__c
                                                , Amount__c 
                                                , (SELECT Id
                                                        , Name
                                                        , Description__c 
                                                    FROM Details__r)
                                            FROM Item__c];
        return ItemDetailRecords ;
    }
}
```

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="dataTableCon">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ItemRecords}" var="feedbackRecord">
            <apex:column value="{!feedbackRecord.Name}" /> 
            <!--....more --- -->
            <!-- list of the children -->
            <apex:column>
               <apex:repeat value="{!itemRecord.Details__r}" var="d">
                        <li><apex:outputField value="{!d.Name}" /></li>
                        <li><apex:outputField value="{!d.Description__c}" />     
                    </apex:repeat>
                </ul>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

ERROR:

> Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Details__r'

UPDATE END::

here is my SOQL and how would I display parent/child relationshiop in VF page?

```
Select Code__c, Order__c, Name, Amount__c, 
     (Select Id, Item__c, Description__c From Details__r) From Item__c
```

Comment: Have you tried using <apex:relatedList> ? See the following for more info:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

If you're not using a standard controller and don't want to you can try using something like <apex:repeat value="{!myParentList} var="parentList"><apex:repeat value="{!parentList.Details__r}" var="childList">

Answer (score 1):

The specific reason for the error is on this line

```
<apex:repeat value="{!itemRecord.Details__r}" var="d">
```

should be

```
<apex:repeat value="{!feedbackRecord.Details__r}" var="d">
```

The inner loop has to reference the `var=` attribute on the `pageBlockTable` as you are referencing the the related list for a single `item__c`